# Can't apply .capitalize() or .title() method to a string

Tags: python, string, methods

I'm trying to create a program in which user will be prompted to enter a new member. Then that member will be added to that a file. Everything is going perfectly but i just can't aplly .title() or .capitalize() method to that members name.

```
member = input("Enter a new member: ")
member.title()

file = open("members.txt", 'r')
existing_members = file.readlines()
file.close()

existing_members.append(member + '\n')

file = open("members.txt", 'w')
file.writelines(existing_members)
file.close()
```

I don't know whats missing but i just want the string that user enters to be titled.

Comment: `member = member.title()` you need to assign it to some variable if you want to use it later or you can do `member = input("Enter a new member: ").title()`

Comment: @5P33DC0R3 Do you want to Have the `member` name in `upper case`? If yes you can use `abc = member.upper()`

Comment: Worth reading [Python's Mutable vs Immutable Types: What's the Difference?](https://realpython.com/python-mutable-vs-immutable-types/#immutable-built-in-data-types-in-python)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. It was my very first question on this site and I'm really impressed with the time it took to get answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The title and capitalize methods return a new string, since the `str` type is immutable in Python and any change to that will create a new object. So you just have to store the modified string into a new variable, preferably with the same name.

Also I strongly recommend using the `open` method using `with` notation, since this way you make sure the file will be closed. In your code if an exception occurs before you hit the `close`, the file will remain open.

Here's my version of your code:

```
member = input("Enter a new member: ")
member = member.title()

with open("members.txt", 'rw') as file_:
    existing_members = file_.readlines()
    existing_members.append(member + '\n')
    file_.writelines(existing_members)
```

Answer (score 0):

title with upper case

```
member = input("Enter a new member: ").upper()
test = "hello"
test.upper() # HELLO
test.title() # Hello
```

Comment: Upper casing the string negates the previous titling so use one or the other, not both.